# getaddrinfo not returning ipv6 details

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, getaddrinfo

I am facing issues in getting `ipv6` `using getaddrinfo()`:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
        int soc = 00;
        struct addrinfo hints,*results,*res;
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        int m = getaddrinfo("myhost","2018",&hints,&results);
        if (m<0)
        {
                printf("getaddrinfo error :  %s\n", gai_strerror(m));
                return 1;
        }
        res=results;
        do
        {
                if(res->ai_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                        struct sockaddr_in6* a= (struct sockaddr_in6*)res->ai_addr;
                        char straddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
                        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &a->sin6_addr, straddr, sizeof(straddr));
                        printf("IP v6 - %s\n",straddr);
                }
                if(res->ai_family == AF_INET)
                {
                        struct sockaddr_in* b= (struct sockaddr_in*)res->ai_addr;
                        const char* dotted_decimal1 = inet_ntoa(b->sin_addr);
                        printf("IP v4 - %s\n",dotted_decimal1);
                }
        }
        while((res=res->ai_next) !=NULL);

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
IP v4 - xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Since I have set `hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC`, it should return me both the details (`ipv4` and `ipv6`). **But it is returning details of ipv4 only.**

Note: on command `ifconfig` I can see both `ipv4` and `ipv6` address.

```
> $ ifconfig
> eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
> inet addr:x.x.x.x  Bcast:x.x.x.x  Mask:255.255.255.128
> inet6 addr: xx::xx:xx:xx:xx/64 Scope:Link
```

1. Can onyone explain me why it is not picking ipv6?
2. Do I need to make any changes on my host (Linux)?

I have removed the actual ip details and replaced with xxxx.

Comment: Just because you have IPv6 on your system does not mean that the name "myhost" is associated with an IPv6 address. This kind of association need to be done in the DNS (network wide) or in `/etc/hosts` (only visible to the local system).

Comment: myhost is just for example.... I have different machine name there

Comment: It was clear to me that "myhost" is just an example. But what I said regarding the DNS/hosts setup for "myhost" is still true even if the actual name is different.

Comment: @kaps Are you using an actual hostname for which you know for certain has that hostname to an ipv6 address mapping , that can be resolved ?

Comment: @kaps what is your goal? Do you want to resolve host name? or do you want to retrive your local IPv6 address?

Comment: @miradham - Yes I am trying to get the ipv6 from a given hostname

Comment: @kaps are you sure that the hostname has IPv6 addres?

Comment: @miradham - **> $ ifconfig
> eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
> inet addr:x.x.x.x  Bcast:x.x.x.x  Mask:255.255.255.128
> inet6 addr: xx::xx:xx:xx:xx/64 Scope:Link**

Comment: @kaps is this IP configuration of `myhost`? If so, then you have only link local IPv6 address. It cannot be used to access outside of LAN

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Thank you.. There was a small mistake in the /etc/hosts.. Now I am able to fetch ipv6 but when I try to connect the server, it says "Invalid argument".. This is due to the scope id not set in the result... can you please share the syntax for the ipv6 entry in /etc/hosts file

Comment: @kaps: there is nothing special with the IPv6 syntax in `/etc/hosts`. For the general syntax see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Representation

Comment: I have below entry in /etc/hosts "fe80::e41b:2c23:a286:77a myhost". Is this correct ?

Answer (score 3):

To retrieve local addresses (since you are using `AI_PASSIVE`), you can (and should) set the `node` parameter to `NULL` instead of specifying an actual name, per the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html):

> If the `AI_PASSIVE` flag is specified in `hints.ai_flags`, and node is `NULL`, then the returned socket addresses will be suitable for `bind(2)`ing a socket that will `accept(2)` connections.

Also, `inet_ntop()` supports `AF_INET`, so you can get rid of your `if` statements and use `inet_ntop()` unconditionally for both address families.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void* getSinAddr(int af, sockaddr *addr)
{
    switch (af)
    {
        case AF_INET:
            return &(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(addr)->sin_addr);

        case AF_INET6:
            return &(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(addr)->sin6_addr);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    addrinfo hints = {}, *results, *res;

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    int m = getaddrinfo(NULL, "2018", &hints, &results);
    if (m < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo error : " << gai_strerror(m) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for(res = results; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next)
    {
        char straddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
        if (inet_ntop(res->ai_family, getSinAddr(res->ai_family, res->ai_addr), straddr, sizeof(straddr)))
            std::cout << "IP - " << straddr << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "inet_ntop error : " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(results);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Remy Lebeay, I ran the code you provided, it gave **ipv4 as "0.0.0.0"** and **ipv6 as "::"**. I removed **hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;** and gave the actual host name and it gave me just the ipv4 again.

Answer (score 2):

> Since I have set hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC it should return me both the details (ipv4 and ipv6)

No, it should not. `getaddrinfo` API does not guarantee to return both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. It returns IP address type that is associated with given host name.

In order to make sure that your code is working fine you can simply check `google.com` host over `80` or `443` ports i.e.

```
 int m = getaddrinfo("google.com","80",&hints,&results);
```

This check returns both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in my Linux PC(fyi, I also don't have global IPv6 address).

If you need to retrieve your local IPv6 address, I would recommend to use `getifaddrs` or read `/proc/net/if_inet6` file in Linux, and `GetAdaptersAddresses` in Windows.
 Also please pay attention that your IPv6 address scope is link local, which is auto generated by OS.